# How to specify a default param in unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Say I have the function shoutout inside my `.profile` file.
When I run `shoutout 'Hello'`, the function prints out `Hello`, which is the expected response. However, I'd like to be able to simply call `shoutout` with no parameters and have the function print out `Foobar`.

How do I specify a default value for $1 with or without variables? Thanks!

```
shoutout() {
    echo $1
}
```

Comment: Because of how you are using the command this is really a shell or bash question, rather than ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
shoutout() {
    echo ${1:-Foobar}
}
```

---

EDIT: Thanks to @ephemient for this extra tid-bit that I wasn't aware of...

To avoid confusing an empty-string argument as a missing argument, omit the colon (`:`):

```
shoutout() {
    echo ${1-Foobar}
}

$ shoutout
Foobar
$ shoutout ""

$
```

Comment: Slight issue which may or may not matter; `shoutout ''` produces "Foobar" rather than "".

Comment: To take care of that case, use `${1-Foobar}` instead of `${1:-Foobar}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
shoutout() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo No arguments.
    else
        echo $1
    fi
}
```